# Stripe: Make transfers from a user's card and not from my account balance

Tags: node.js, flutter, stripe-payments

I have already followed Stripe's [documentation to make transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers). I get an error telling me that I do not have sufficient funds on my balance. In my case, I would like not to transfer the money from my account but from the card of the user making the purchase. I specify that I need to make transfers because I can have several accounts connected for a single payment.

Here is the steps I follow:

1. On the client side (Flutter), I ask a user to enter his bank card information. I then generate a PaymentMethod object that I send to my server (Node.js).
2. (server side), I execute the `paymentIntent.create` method

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: amount,
      currency: "eur",
      payment_method: paym,// id get from client side
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      transfer_group: "{ORDER1}",
    });
```

3. (server side), create transfers

```
        const transfer1 = await stripe.transfers.create({
          amount: amount / 2,
          currency: "eur",
          destination: "acct_###########",
          transfer_group: "{ORDER1}",
          source_transaction: ?,
        });
```

I know that I have to fill in the `source_transaction` field to make the link between PaymentIntent and Transfer. I can retrieve this information in the PaymentIntent object with the `charge` field but it is empty. This means that I must first validate the payment on the client side before making the transfer.

Only when I validate it on the customer side, I receive the following error `No such payment_intent` when I execute:

```
StripePayment.confirmPaymentIntent(PaymentIntent(
                paymentMethodId: result.data['paymentIntent']['payment_method'],
                clientSecret: result.data['paymentIntent']['client_secret']))
```

Is there something I do wrong or missing ? Do you have an example of a simple implementation ?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: you need to specify the source.

Comment: @Wils can you explain me ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Payment Intent ID as the `source_transaction` value.

Comment: No I have to indicate the charge